# Amazon Cognito: What is the AuthFlow when the user logs in through facebook/google/other idps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm not getting a clear picture of the authentication process when a user logs in through another idp. My use case being for an app that does not need aws credentials.

If I get a token back after a user logs in from facebook for example, how do I connect that with a user in the userpool or my own database which may contain the user's app specific data?

user logs into facebook -> gets token back -> send token to amazon cognito (?) -> get back cognito token (?)

I'm currently looking for documentation on how to implement the above but there doesn't seem to be a direct link to it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation.html

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a [social IdP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social.html) such as Facebook and use the [authorize endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html).

Alternatively, Cognito now supports hosted signup and login pages for your application. You just need to create a [Cognito domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-assign-domain.html), and set [App Client Settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html).